# Alternative for join in Redis

Tags: c#, redis

I have created two hash key value pair in Redis named Person and Account. The Person key has the first name and last name of the person and the Account Key contains account type and savings. Now I want to do a join similar to SQL joins(inner join) to retrieve the account type and savings of each person from both the hash values.

Kindly help me out to find a solution to this problem and could anyone please help me in setting a primary key and foreign key in Redis hash key value pairs.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b8j8I.png)

Answer (score 0):

Redis is not meant to serve for this purpose. But still as a workaround you can try something like this.

In each of your Person hash have a value representing account id.

```
hmset person:0 first_name aswathy last_name jacob account_id 1
```

Your account hashes will look something like this

```
hmset account:1 type x savings xxx
```

Now in order to achieve a join. Write a lua code, or a application logic like this.

```
temp = hgetall person:0 -> temp is a hashmap
temp1 = hgetall "account:"+temp.get(account_id) -> this will get you all the info in that account
put temp and temp1 in a map and return it
```

Resulted map will give you a result equivalent to the join.